# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shop'

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm currently working on an e-commerce Django project. After rewriting my code, I can't get to display my shop products due to a `ModuleNotFoundError`. It says that Module 'shop' is not there but I already ensured that it is declared in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Traceback(Updated):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\msi\Desktop\DaveTeo_WebPOS_project\daveteo_webpos_project\shop\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from shop.models import Bikes, Category, Item_Category, Gears, Parts, Services
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shop'
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from shop.models import Bikes, Category, Item_Category, Gears, Parts, Services
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_interface',
    'colorfield',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'admin_site',
    'authenticate',
    'base_app',
    'canvas',
    'pos',
    'shop',
]
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Category(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bicycle Categories'
        verbose_name        = 'Category'

class Brands(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Brands'
        verbose_name        = 'Brand'
    
class Bikes(models.Model):
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand                   = models.ForeignKey(Brands, related_name='bike_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price                   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to='items\shop_bikes', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sold                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    num_stock               = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    num_sold                = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bicycles'
        verbose_name        = 'Bikes'
    
class Item_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Item Categories'
        verbose_name        = 'Category'

class Gears(models.Model):
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Item_Category, related_name='gears', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand                   = models.ForeignKey(Brands, related_name='gear_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price                   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to='items\gears', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sold                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    num_stock               = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    num_sold                = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Riding Gears'
        verbose_name        = 'Gears'

class Parts(models.Model):
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Item_Category, related_name='parts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand                   = models.ForeignKey(Brands, related_name='part_brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price                   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image                   = models.ImageField(upload_to='items\parts', blank=True, null=True)
    is_sold                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at              = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    num_stock               = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    num_sold                = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bicycle Parts'
        verbose_name        = 'Parts'

    
class Services(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering            = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Services Offered'
        verbose_name        = 'Services'
```

Template:

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px solid grey">
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          {% for category in categories %}
          <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
                     <h5 style="color: black;">
                          {{ category.name }} {{ category.items.count }}
                     </h5>
                </a>
          </li>
          {% endfor %}
     </ul>
</d
```

I have read many documentations about this and I already make sure that I follow the proper project structure like this.

[image: My Project's structure]

I already do migrations, and ensure that the configurations are right. I'm trying to display the contents of shop.models to a template for the shop's browsing feature.

Comment: The error is coming from `tests.py` file in `shop` app. Can you show those few lines of the `tests.py`?

Also the models, details etc are not needed for this question. Make sure you add only details relevant to the question / issue

Comment: I'll try to minimize the details for my future questions, thank you. 

regarding the test.py, I saw that and I already cleared it. Now whenever I ran a debug on my views.py, the same error shows but the traceback comes from views.py now. 

I can still run the server properly but the items are not showing. My guess is that it's because of that error

Comment: Can you update the question with the current stack trace?

Comment: Done. I tried different methods on it now like rewriting and even updating my IDE in case the reason is an outdated compiler. But nothing happens. It seems like the model.py is also involved but I have no idea since there are only few documentations about the error "ModuleNotFoundError"

Comment: What happens when you try it this way `from .models import Bikes, Category, Item_Category, Gears, Parts, Services` ?

Comment: check your shop  app's  init  file, ( check any import statements there)

Comment: what code changes did you made, did you renamed apps?   models ?

Comment: try django shell too

Comment: @ArunT it becomes an ImportError telling attempted import with no known parent package.

`Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
  File "C:\Users\msi\Desktop\DaveTeo_WebPOS_project\daveteo_webpos_project\shop\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Bikes, Category, Item_Category, Gears, Parts, Services
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @Jisson I haven't modified any apps or models in my app ever since I rewrote the code. I'm trying to rewrite it again in case I missed something. the "shop" app's __init__.py is present but its empty

Comment: did you tried absolute import?  from shop.model import Bikes, Category...

Comment: also try removeing all your __pycache__ folders

Comment: It is somehow working now after I rewrote the code. Weird. But I guess the reason why those errors show is because I only run the debugging on a single file. and it's only trying to find other modules? maybe. Anyway, thank you for all the answers!